# Книги по алгоритмам

Tags: алгоритм, книги

Ищу книгу по основам алгоритмизации. Главный требование - это простой и доступный стиль изложения материала в книге и была предназначена для новичков в этом деле. Алгоритмы - это моя самая слабая часть в программирование, поэтому я хочу поработать над ней. Поэтому прошу посоветовать книгу. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 5):

[**Кормена**](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2429691/) почитайте, базовых знаний *(если читать с самого начала)* вообще не требуется, нам начали преподавать по первой части книги еще в 8 классе.

Да и вообще, серьезный багаж знаний необходим **только для строгого математического обоснования корректности алгоритмов и оценок сложности,** да и то, для понимания большинства доказательств, думаю, ваших знаний будет достаточно *(тем более, что вещи типа `группового` и `амортизационного` анализа в книге вводятся постепеннно).*

Answer (score 2):

Трилогия Кнута (Книга 1 - Основные алгоритмы, Книга 2 - Сортировка и поиск, Книга 3 - Получисленные алгоритмы) - эти труды могут быть достаточно сложоусоваиваемыми...я понял суть Вашего вопроса, но это хорошие книги на самом деле.
Т.Кормен - Алгоритмы построение и анализ.

Comment: мне нужно что то полегче чем эти книги. Я ничего не имею против этих книг, но чтобы их читать нужны базовые знания по алгоритмам.

Answer (score 2):

Вот тут богатый выбор:
[Алгоритмы, компьютерная алгебра](http://www.ph4s.ru/book_pc_algoritm.html)

Answer (score 2):

Вирта можно почитать. Алгоритмы и структуры данных.
у нас как раз перед Кнутом был.

Answer (score 2):

[Дасгупты, Пападимитриу, Вазирани **"Алгоритмы"**](http://habrahabr.ru/company/spbau/blog/222427/) бесплатно (в комментах можно и в бумажном виде заказать)

[Стивен С. Скиена **"Теория алгоритмов"**](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/22486690/)

Лучше учебников (не толстенных) не видел.

Comment: Линк на Скиена неправильный. Должно быть: http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6290126/

Answer (score 1):

Ну и для полноты Роберт Седжвик Алгоритмы на C++. Фундаментальные алгоритмы и структуры данных.

Answer (score 1):

Также посоветую Emaxx http://e-maxx.ru/algo/ , очень много алгоритмов, с оценкой асимптотики, доказательствами и примерами на с++, а также указаны пример задач на использование этих алгоритмов.