# Подскажите сайт с упражнениями с ответами по алгоритмам

Tags: алгоритм, книги

Я освоил javascript,учусь у школе,теперь хочу углубить свои знания в алгоритмах,посоветуйте сайт или учебник с  большим количеством упражнений на программирование,желательно без большого количества математики

Comment: Кнут Д. Искусство программирования.

Comment: я же школьник,а там много жести,и я просил без математики (желательно)

Comment: а кто сказал, что будет легко? :-D

Comment: Специально созданная тема для книг по алгоритмам: [Книги по алгоритмам](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/54972/Книги-по-алгоритмам?rq=1)

Comment: @abascakov: алгоритмы без математики — никак. ))

Comment: Вот тут можно порешать задачки на любом языке, с проверкой ответа.              https://projecteuler.net/archives здесь эти задачи на русском, но ответы проверить можно только на английском сайте http://euler.jakumo.org/problems/showall.html.  Еще есть https://leetcode.com/problemset/algorithms/